# Dominant frequency extraction when doing FFT returns wrong frequency

Tags: python, fft, frequency

I saved an accelerometer sensor data (time, x axis, y axis, and z axis) in a csv file. I'm trying to get the FFT from each axis. My graph is as follows:

[image]

Now, I want to extract the dominant frequencies from each FFT plot and get its corresponding amplitude. After making some research I came up with the code:

```
def Freq(self):
    
    freqs = arange(1, self.N, 1)[:int(self.N/2) - 1]
    Amptsx = (2/self.N)* abs( fft(self.fx)[:int(self.N/2)] )[1:]
    Amptsy = (2/self.N)* abs( fft(self.fy)[:int(self.N/2)] )[1:]
    Amptsz = (2/self.N)* abs( fft(self.fz)[:int(self.N/2)] )[1:]
    
    
    print 'The highest frequency in the x axis is:', round(np.argmax(Amptsx),6)
    print 'The highest frequency in the y axis is:', round(np.argmax(Amptsy),6)
    print 'The highest frequency in the z axis is:', round(np.argmax(Amptsz),6)
    
    print 'The highest amplitude in the x axis is:', round(np.max(Amptsx),6) 
    print 'The highest amplitude in the y axis is:', round(np.max(Amptsy),6)
    print 'The highest amplitude in the z axis is:', round(np.max(Amptsz),6) 
    
    return freqs, Amptsx, Amptsy, Amptsz
```

My results for amplitude are accurate but the frequencies are not. My results are as follows:

```
The highest frequency in the x axis is: 0.0.
The highest frequency in the y axis is: 1.0.
The highest frequency in the z axis is: 15.0.
The highest amplitude in the x axis is: 0.768894.
The highest amplitude in the y axis is: 0.59046.
The highest amplitude in the z axis is: 0.3679.
```

My guess is that my frequencies are rounded down. I've tried to fix it with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be an off-by-one error. The `[1:]` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what would you suggest doing?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

> ```
> freqs = arange(1, self.N, 1)[:int(self.N/2) - 1]
> Amptsx = (2/self.N)* abs( fft(self.fx)[:int(self.N/2)] )[1:]
> ```

> ```
> print 'The highest frequency in the x axis is:', round(np.argmax(Amptsx),6)
> ```

1. The frequency and amplitude arrays are not properly aligned, meaning that the amplitude corresponding to a given frequency has a different index in the `Amptsx` array than the frequency has in the `freqs` array.

   The reason is that by using `[:int(self.N/2) - 1]` you remove one extra item from the *end* of `freqs` whereas by using `[1:]` you remove one extra item from the *start* of `Amptsx`.

   You should either remove one item from the end or from the start in *both* arrays, depending on which one has the correct meaning in your application.

   I suspect that you do this to remove the value for the zero frequency – i.e., a constant offset in the sensor values – from the start of the array, so in that case you should change `[:int(self.N/2) - 1]` to `[1:int(self.N/2)]` for `freqs`.
2. `argmax` gives you the *index* of the highest value in `Amptsx`, which is not a frequency. You should use that index to get the frequency value from `freqs`.

Comment: After writing the answer I think that the first point might even be correct (I don't know exactly) and the second point is the real issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and time! I did end up doing the shifting you described in point 1. For the second point, if I use `round(np.argmax(freqs),6)` , how would I be able to determine the frequency from each axis? Like how could I get that in the x axis, the highest frequency is 2.02246Hz, 3.01934Hz for the y axis, and 17.0172Hz for the z axis?

Comment: You use the results of `argmax(Amptsx)` etc. as an index for `freqs`. `argmax(freqs)` gives the index of the highest value in `freqs` which is not very useful.

Comment: _You use the results of `argmax(Amptsx)` etc. as an index for `freqs`._ 
 Would you mind elaborating a little more into that?

Comment: An index is the thing you put into `[]`: `freqs[argmax(Amptsx)]`